# How to programatically set the shipping amount in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a Wordpress plugin that handles the shipping and delivery for WooCommerce.

I want to simply tell my WooCommerce [cart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html) (or [order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html)), this is what the shipping amount is.

I have tried directly setting `WC()->cart->shipping_amount = $amount;`,
and also doing `->add_fee( $shippingServiceName, $amount );`
in both cases the `shipping_amount` on the cart remains at `0`.

How do I set the shipping amount?

Comment: for some reason I don't know... I can't seem to locate `WC()->cart->shipping_amount` but only `WC()->cart->shipping_total`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up setting it directly on the order instead of on the cart;
Here is the method I created and used in my "complete purchase" processing :

```
function addShippingToOrder( $order, $shipping_amount, $shipping_name ) {

        $shipping_tax = array(); 
        $shipping_rate = new WC_Shipping_Rate( '', $shipping_name, 
                                      $shipping_amount, $shipping_tax, 
                                      'custom_shipping_method' );
        $order->add_shipping($shipping_rate);

}
```

---

*I also needed to save the shipping amount when I was in the cart logic, and then retrieve it when I was in the order logic, and I did that with a custom cart "session" variable :*
 `WC()->session->set( 'my_custom_shipping_amount', $amt );` and
 `WC()->session->get( 'my_custom_shipping_amount' )`

---

This is a very simple answer, but it took me the longest time to figure out - I even ended up creating a plugin especially for debugging changes to WC_Orders : [WooCommerce Order Debugger Plugin](https://github.com/krisrandall/woocommerce-order-debugger-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'apply_static_rate', 10, 2);
function apply_static_rate($rates, $package)
    {                   
        foreach($rates as $key => $value) {
            $rates[$key]->cost  =   150;    // your amount                  

        }
        return $rates;
}
```